# can onclient click event update a label

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms page that contains six text box inputs.

When a user tries to submit the form, I want to compare all six inputs to ensure all of the values are unique.

I know I can do this using code behind, but I would prefer to do this client-side. I know i can create a Javascript function to validate the input and cancel the form submission using return validate() on onClientclick.

The onclientclick event needs to:
1 cancel the submission
2 show an error message

Please let me know if this is possible.
I could not find an event handler for onClientclick.

Comment: Any reason you're not using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a normal event handler in code behind because that requires a postback.
Use jQuery for the validation and setting the error message.

Comment: How about using javascript? Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: Javascript will work. I'm a beginner on it though and should test it before posting, which I can't do now since I'm driving. I'll post a script later if no-one is faster.

Comment: jQuery is Javascript; it's a library that adds some capabilities to those you have with "vanilla" JS. It can be useful to abstract out the boilerplate code of sending an AJAX call and receiving the response, but it's not 100% necessary to do this.